# Javascript setTimeOut causes leak

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, widget, settimeout

When profiling my page in chrome profiler something caught my attention, I noticed something odd. The number of nodes does ramp up.
When disabling most of the page, I ended up to with a timer function.

The timer is a jquery widget, which uses the function setTimeOut(). The line which is triggered in a continious loop and was detected by the profiler:

```
this._id = setTimeout($.proxy(this._callback, this) , this.options.delay);
```

Other parts of the timer code:

```
$(function() {
    $.widget('timer', {
        options: {
            delay: 1000,
            repeat: false,
            autostart: true
        },

        _timerId: null,
        _id: null,
        _index: null,
        _state: 0,

        /**
         * The constructor
         *
         * @private
         */
        _create: function() {
            if (this.options.autostart) {
                this._state = 1;
                this._id = setTimeout($.proxy(this._callback, this), this.options.delay);
            }
        },

        _callback: function()
        {
            if (typeof this.options.callback == 'function') {
                $.proxy(this.options.callback, this.element).call(this, ++this._index);
            }

            if (this.options.repeat && this._state == 1 && (typeof this.options.repeat == "boolean" || parseInt(this.options.repeat) > this._index)) {
                this._id = setTimeout($.proxy(this._callback, this) , this.options.delay);
            } else {
                this._timerId = null;
            }
        },
```

The screenshot of the profiler:

[image: profiler result]

the profiler did run 405 seconds, as you can see both the nodes does ramp up. and are not collected by garbage collector even after hours the nodes are still increasing, 30min its already over 25K nodes and the listeners are stable.

My thoughts it my be the combination of using widget structure and the setTimeOut function, but I did not found any useful topics about that.

Is this caused by the code of is this caused by the profiler?

Comment: It's not going to be the profiler causing it. That would make the profiler completely useless. It's not at all clear what your code is actually doing, but to have that kind of memory leak generally means you're continually inserting elements in to the DOM and not removing all of them when needed.

Comment: I would try proxying (or .binding) your function once and assign that to an object variable, instead of doing it every time you need to execute it.  You could even define _callback as a proxied/bound function.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, in this case the timer is used to update a clock on the page. as far i know the its updates the time with field.html(*new value*);

Even with the callback disabled, same result

Comment: @James can you give me an example how to do this?